# Ignore trailing whitespaces in comparisons using collation in Oracle 12c

Tags: database, oracle, collation, nls-sort, nls-comp

I want to have the Oracle database regard 'abc' and 'abc      ' VARCHAR2s as being equal in all comparisons (WHERE-clauses, sorting, ...). Basically this means ignoring the trailing whitespaces like the PADSPACE collations do in MariaDB/MySQL.

There are solutions available like using the RTRIM function, but I am specifically looking at a solution using collation because I need something that is transparent and does not have a huge impact on performance (ie. applying RTRIM on the left side of my equation). I do seem to remember that at some point in the past on an older Oracle installation I managed to achieve this behaviour by just selecting the right collation (ie. setting NLS_COMP to linguistic, and then some value for NLS_SORT). Now a few years later and with a newer Oracle installation (12c) I cannot seem to replicate the same behaviour anymore. It is just a memory though, so I could be mixing it up with a usecase in MySQL rather than an 'older Oracle'.

Is there any collation in Oracle12c that ignores trailing whitespaces in comparisons (ie. an equivalent to the PADSPACE collations in MySQL/MariaDB)? I have tried multiple collations already (BINARY_AI, FRENCH, XFRENCH, FRENCH_M, UCA0610_DUCET and UCA0620_DUCET) to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can ignore spaces completely, e.g. with `UCA0620_DUCET_AI`; I don't know if there's a way to only ignore them at the end of a string though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. It is indeed already a step closer to what I need but has the limitation that it ignores ALL spaces, as you mentioned.